# Do independent mobile platforms(ios,android...) connect one transaction server?

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, socketserver

I want to develop one transaction server which sends/receives texts to independent clients. I decide to use java language to develop transaction server and i have three clients which are android, Ios and Win8 to communicate with transaction server. Well, is it possible to develop that kind of project? Is it possible to use network library of android and network library of Ios to connect one transaction server which is written by java? I'll be happy to see your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is - yes it's possible.

Extended answer is - you can write your web-service on Java (or any another language) and it will process requests from different clients whatever which platform they use. As soon as it's web-service it should to work with clients via HTTP protocol. Above HTTP protocol you can use JSON or XML to encapsulate your data. Your clients will know a list of requests to your server and each of them will implement its own network engine to prepare request, send requests and perform server's response.

[There is](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) example how to implement simple PHP server for iOS. You can get common ideas from there and adapt it for your needs.